# How to remove rows from DF as result of a groupby query?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'site': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'day': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'hour': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'clicks': [100, 200, 50, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 20]})

#   site  day  hour  clicks
# 0    a    1     1     100
# 1    a    1     2     200
# 2    a    1     3      50
# 3    b    1     1       0
# 4    b    1     2       0
# 5    b    1     3       0
# 6    a    2     1      10
# 7    a    2     2       0
# 8    a    2     3      20
```

And I want to remove all rows for a site/day, where there were 0 clicks. So in the example above, I would want to remove the rows with site='b' and day =1.

I can basically group them and show where the sum is 0 for a day/site:

```
print(df.groupby(['site', 'day'])['clicks'].sum() == 0)
```

But how would now be straight-forward way to remove the rows from original dataframe where that condition applies?
Solution I am having so far is that I iterate over group and save all tuples of site/day in a list, and then separately remove all rows that have that combinations of site/day. That works but, I am sure there must be a more functional and elegant way to achieve that result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1

#### Using `groupby`, `transform` and boolean indexing:

```
df[df.groupby(['site', 'day'])['clicks'].transform('sum') != 0]
```

Output:

```
  site  day  hour  clicks
0    a    1     1     100
1    a    1     2     200
2    a    1     3      50
6    a    2     1      10
7    a    2     2       0
8    a    2     3      20
```

## Option 2

#### Using `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby(['site', 'day']).filter(lambda x: x['clicks'].sum() != 0)
```

Output:

```
  site  day  hour  clicks
0    a    1     1     100
1    a    1     2     200
2    a    1     3      50
6    a    2     1      10
7    a    2     2       0
8    a    2     3      20
```

Comment: was just about to comment about `filter` (-: